# Mixed reality in Android device using Unity(w/ OpenCV?)

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

I'm a fourth year student currently doing my thesis project(Noob in programming). What I want to ask is that is it possible to create a mobile app in Unity that has the following specifications:
- Mixed Reality
- Hand Tracking
- has an A.I. (Image comparison)
I've done some research but all I've saw is only in AR. If it is possible what course of action should I take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible.**

I suggest you to use:

**ARStuff:**
Vuforia, EasyAR or ARCore/ARKit (depending of your mobile target).

**HandTracking:**
One of the best SDK's I try about HandTracking with AR is Manomotion (https://www.manomotion.com/)

**Image Comparison:**
As you suggest, OpenCV is a good choice, there are some "bridges" to use OpenCV on Unity Store.